# Bash match on any lines that have any number of whitespace up to #

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I need to clean up a config file before a source it.
I need to remove any lines that have

- Start with `#`
- Any number of white space then a `#`
- blank lines
- Remove (and including) `#` and everything after it if line starts with a string.

Example config:

```sh
# comment
     # comment
dog=woof
cat=meow
moose=huuuuu #comment

# comment
### comment
```

I have this right now

```sh
config_params="$(cat ./config_file.conf | grep -v "^#.* | awk -F '=' '{print$1}')"
```

The problem is line 2,      `# comment` any number of space up to a `#`. How can I match to remove lines like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F= 'NF == 2 {sub(/[[:blank:]]*#.*/, ""); print}' file

dog=woof
cat=meow
moose=huuuuu
```

Or if you want to print only key names then use:

```sh
awk -F= 'NF == 2 {sub(/[[:blank:]]*#.*/, ""); print $1}' file

dog
cat
moose
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
config_params=$(awk -F'=' '!/^[[:space:]]*#/{print $1}' ./config_file.conf)
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/IDzB25):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='# comment
     # comment
dog=woof
cat=meow
moose=huuuuu #comment
 
# comment
### comment'
awk -F'=' '!/^[[:space:]]*#/{print $1}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
dog
cat
moose
```

Here, `^[[:space:]]*#` matches start of a string, then zero or more whitespaces, and then a `#`. The `!` negates the regex match result, so only the lines that do not match this pattern are "taken", and then their Field 1 values are only printed.

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor, your answer good as well!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another working solution by using `sed`:

```sh
config=$(sed -r -e '/^$/d' -e '/^ *#/d' -e 's/^(.+)(#.*)$/\1/' [[YOUR_CONFIG_FILE_NAME]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `sed`.

```
$ cat file
# comment
     # comment
dog=woof
cat=meow
moose=huuuuu #comment

# comment
### comment

$ sed -E 's/ *#.*//; /^$/d;' file
dog=woof
cat=meow
moose=huuuuu

$ temp=$(mktemp)
$ sed -E 's/ *#.*//; /^$/d;' file>$temp
$ . $temp
$ echo $moose
huuuuu
```

Also, [UUoC](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award) is an antipattern, and chaining regex tools kind of is too.
And why are you saving just the keys to a variable without values?
(I added a closing paren & quote.)

If that's really what you wanted, then instead of

```
config_params="$(cat ./config_file.conf | grep -v "^#.* | awk -F '=' '{print$1}')"
```

try

```
config_params="$(awk -F '=' '/^ *(#.*)*$/{next} {print $1}' ./config_file.conf)"
```

Though I thought the point was to `source` them...